# Duplicate usernames in FreeRadius are rejected in authentication

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I have FreeRADIUS with Mysql backend, I am feeding the mysql tables radcheck and userinfo with data for fields of username . value (radcheck table) . and username in table (userinfo)

RADIUS responds correctly to requests coming from other applications but the problem is 1/3 of the usernames are duplicated, for example 1221 is the username and exists multiple times , each with different password .
now this username gets reject response from RADIUS , even username and password are correct

Is there a way to configure DaloRADIUS/FreeRADIUS to do full match and work correctly even usernames are duplicated?

I fill both tables , radcheck and userinfo with usernames and passwords using php and mysql query

Answer (score 0):

Do not put duplicate users in your database. That way is asking for trouble.

What is likely happening is FreeRADIUS is doing an SQL query for the username, and getting back one entry from the database. It then compares the password. If it happens to be the one that was returned, then all well and good. If the password entered was one of the *other* entries in the database, then the authentication will fail. There is no way for FreeRADIUS to know which entry to pull from the database, because you have used the same username.

In short, just don't do that. Use unique usernames.